# proof about polynom of invertable matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like some help with a proof.

I have two matrices A and B

I need to prove that if A or B is invertable then the characteristic polynom of AB is the same as the characteristic polynom of BA

any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Do you mean the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: And if you do, your tag is not the right one; I would tag this Matrix or Linear Lagebra, and Eigenvalues.

Comment: i will edit that. thank you

Comment: Perhaps by "invertable" [sic] , the OP meant "commutative" matrices...?

Comment: not i meant invertable. i thought maybe it has something to do with that an invertable matrix can be written as I*row operations

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A$ is invertible. Then $BA=A^{-1}(AB)A$, so $AB$ and $BA$ are similar.

Comment: Well there ya' go. Elegant.

Answer (score 1):

We will use the facts that

- The characteristic polynomial $P[M](x) = \det ( M - xI )$.
- The determinant of a product of two matrices is the product of the determinants.

Say $A$ is invertible; then $\det A \neq 0$ and

$$
P[AB](x) = \det(AB - xI) = 
\det A \det (A^{-1}) \det(AB - xI) 
\\ = \det A \det(B - xA^{-1}) = \det A ( \det(B - xA^{-1}) \det A ) \frac1{\det A}
\\ 
= \det A \det(BA - xA^{-1}A) \frac1{\det A}= \det (BA-xI) = P[BA](x)
$$

Comment: great answer! thank you Mark